# Where did it come from? (derivative of exponential)

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

We all know this rule:

> $\text{If } y = a^{f(x)} \text{ then } y' = a^{f(x)} \: f'(x)\ln a$

In my book there is the example:

Find $\frac{d}{dx}\left((x^{2} + 1)^{\sin x}\right)$

According to the rule, my answer is:

$(x^{2} + 1)^{\sin x} \cdot \cos x \cdot \ln(x^{2} + 1)$

But the answer of the book was:

$$(x^{2} + 1)^{\sin x}\left(\frac{2x \sin x}{x^{2} + 1} + \cos x \cdot \ln(x^{2} + 1)\right)$$

So, where did $\frac{2x \sin x}{x^{2} + 1}$ come from?

Comment: You can take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492320/fracddx-left-left1x2-rightx-right/1492332#1492332). You can find nice and more general tidy answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that this is not homework and go ahead to give a full solution.

As others have said, your rule only works for constant $a$. Following the hint in danielson's answer and setting $y=f(x)$, you have $$\log y=\sin x\log\left(1+x^2\right)$$
and differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ and using the chain and product rules gives $$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos x\log\left(1+x^2\right)+\frac{2x\sin x}{1+x^2}\quad\text{so that}\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=y\left(\cos x\log\left(1+x^2\right)+\frac{2x\sin x}{1+x^2}\right).$$Substituting back for $y$ gives the result.

Tell me if you don't understand any of the applications of the chain rule.

Comment: it's not homework!!

Comment: thank you, I wonder what is the rule if it's not constant?, I mean without add ln to both sides

Comment: You just have to use tricks like this one, or the equivalent given in Peter's answer. Note that when I differentiated $\log y$ with respect to $x$, I was also using the chain rule because $y$ is a function of $x$ and so $d/dx(\log y(x))=(d(\log y)/dy)(dy/dx)$. This is called implicit differentiation, in case you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Well, my last comment is not really accurate. There is such rule. And it is the one we used precisely, just do the same procedure for arbitrary $y=f(x)$. But then of course the result will be complicated and not easy to remember: hence there is no such rule written. It is easier to use the trick each time.

Comment: @user283144: This method does not always work, such as for finding $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)$ because its logarithm does not exist when $x = 0$. Writing "$\ln(x^3)$" when $x$ could be $0$ is simply wrong. The bottom line is that you should always check that whatever you do is allowed. It is **not allowed** to take logarithm of $0$, just as it is not allowed to divide by $0$.

Answer (score 6):

The rule that you quote is only valid if a is a constant.

Comment: what is the rule if it's not constant

Comment: Apply the chain rule to the composition of the function x->(f(x),g(x)) with the function (v,w)->v^w. This yields that the derivative of f^g is the sum of two components. The first component pretends that f is constant (using your original formula) and the second component pretends that g is constant (using the formula for the derivative of a power).

Answer (score 3):

Start with $$f(x)=e^{\ln(x^2+1)\sin(x)}$$

The chain rule gives

$$f'(x)=e^{\ln(x^2+1)\sin(x)}\times (\ln(x^2+1)\sin(x))'=(x^2+1)^{\sin(x)}(\ln(x^2+1)\sin(x))'$$

Take it from here.

Comment: To compute $(ln(x^2+1)sin(x))'$, you need the product rule.

Comment: Use `\ln` and `\sin` to get the upright versions. I'm surprised you have 15k reputation without knowing that?

Comment: @user21820 or bothering...

Answer (score 2):

The rule that you have given is for $\textit{constant}$ $a$, while the base of your function is a $\textit{function}$. So the rule does not apply here.

To fix this, let $f(x) = (x^2 + 1)^{\sin(x)}$ and consider $\ln(f(x))$. Differentiate the new function, while also utilizing a nice property of exponents inside logarithmic functions, and try to deduce the derivative of the original function from this.

---

Comment: what is the rule if it's not constant

Answer (score 0):

The rule is
$$\frac d{dx}u(x)^{v(x)}=v(x)u(x)^{v(x)-1}\frac{du}{dx}+u(x)^{v(x)}(\ln u(x))\frac{dv}{dx}.$$
You can derive this by the method of [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation#Composite_exponent). It is a special case of the two-variable chain rule:
$$\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}.$$
Notice how it simplifies to familiar rules if either $u(x)$ or $v(u)$ is a constant. This makes the general formula easy to remember. If $u$ is variable and $v$ is constant then,
$$(u^v)
'=vu^{v-1}u';$$
if $v$ is variable and $u$ is constant, then
$$(u^v)'=u^v(\ln u)v';$$
if $u$ and $v$ are both variables, then
$$(u^v)'=vu^{v-1}u'+u^v(\ln u)v'.$$