# How to differentiate $y=e^ {\frac{-1}{2}x^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+2x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

We need to find the maximum point of the curve, M. I know that we must find the $dy/dx$ of the equation of the curve and set it to $0$. However, I'm having trouble differentiating the equation. I'm aware of the product/quotient rule, but didn't get the correct answer despite trying several times.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the expression in the title is, I tried to edit it. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: use the product and the chain rule

Comment: Please show your work so that we can precisely address the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Daniel Not too familiar with MathJax!

Comment: @dbanet I can't take a picture of my working. However, I have used $u'v+v'u$ to differentiate the equation which didn't work. I suspect the problem lies somewhere over there.

Comment: For example, good questions about technicalities of function differentiation, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492320/how-to-compute-fracddx-left-left1x2-rightx-right?rq=1), include the work, the answer the OP (original poster) arrived at, and the right answer. Besides, please also restrain from putting information irrelevant to the issue of the question in the post. The comment thread is the right place to communicate with editors. Good luck!

Comment: @dbanet Thanks a lot dbanet. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the product rule, $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x) = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$

Here, $$f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$ $$g(x) = \sqrt{1+2x^2}$$

To find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),

$$f'(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} \cdot (-x)$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{4x}{2\sqrt{1+2x^2}}$$

Comment: the derivative of $f(x)$ is wrong

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$(e^{-1/2x^2})'=e^{-1/2x^2} \cdot (-x)$$
and $$(\sqrt{1+2x^2})'=\frac{1}{2}(1+2x^2)^{-1/2}\cdot 4x$$
and the first derivative is given by $$-{\frac {x{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{x}^{2}}} \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-1 \right) }{
\sqrt {2\,{x}^{2}+1}}}
$$ (simplified)